# Invalidating IdentityServer session and access token when a user's password changes

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, identityserver4

I'm using IdentityServer4 in ASP.NET Core 2.2. The client application (RP) is an API, also an ASP.NET Core 2.2 application. The user logs in using the authorization code flow and gets a cookie from IdentityServer (`idsrv`). They then get an authorization code and and access token for the API (RP).

I want to be able to revoke a user's existing login session and access tokens in some cases, e.g. if their password has been reset. In IdentityServer I've implemented added my own authentication scheme:

```
            .AddCookie("MyAuthenticationScheme", options =>
            {
                options.SessionStore = new MyTicketStore();
                options.EventsType = typeof(MyCookieAuthenticationEvents);
            })
```

This allows me to invalidate the user's IdentityServer session on the server before the authentication ticket expires. For example, when the user is signed in I add a claim that stores the date their password was last changed and in `MyCookieAuthenticationEvents.ValidatePrincipal()` I check that it has not been changed since, as suggested on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-2.2#react-to-back-end-changes

I want to do the same with the access token they use the access the RP. If the user's password has changed (and in some other cases) I want the access token to be invalidated immediately, rather than waiting for it to expire. I'm using reference tokens and have implemented `IProfileService` and `ICustomTokenValidator`. In `IProfileService.GetProfileDataAsync` I copy the password change date claim to the access token claims collection and in `ICustomTokenValidator.ValidateAccessTokenAsync` I again check that claim against the real user.

This works, but it seems quite convoluted and complicated and I wonder if there is a simpler way to accomplish this - it seems like this should be a common requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using reference tokens, all you need to in order to invalidate the token is to remove it from whatever implementation of `IPersistedGrantStore` you have and the next time reference token is attempted to be validated through introspection, it will be invalid since it will no longer exist.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't seem much simpler than the ICustomTokenValidator. I still need access to the claims (to check if the user's password has changed since the token was issued) and in ICustomTokenValidator they've already been parsed for me.

Comment: Well it is up to you, but the way I suggested, you can actually "immediately" invalidate the token. The way you are suggesting, the reference token is still sitting in the store completely valid until the next time token is requested. Manipulating the persisted grant store in general is likely a better approach than putting business logic into `ICustomTokenValidator` (but of course, this statement is highly opinionated by me).

Comment: You're right, the token could be removed from the grant store before it's requested, but is there a scenario where that makes a practical difference?

Comment: @EM0 in your particular scenario - I can't think of anything. You've asked for a simpler way, and this is imo a simpler way, because on password change you would have extra call to clear existing grants for user (call once) as opposed to the date comparisons you are doing now (call every time). My approach gives you a way to "invalidate a token immediately", your approach "invalidates token request if user's password has changed in x time". It is a more generic abstraction over what you are actually trying to achieve overall. By no means you actually have to implement it though.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean now! Unfortunately I can't rely on IdentityServer code always being notified of things that require the session to be invalidated - it has to check the user database to be sure. So it looks like in my case there isn't any advantage to implementing `IPersistedGrantStore` then. Thank you for pointing it out though!